Cancel datastore moving on esxi 6.7
it's my first post here but I need your help.
In my company, we're migrating to a new server, so I'm moving the data virtual disk of a VM from a local storage to a NFS, so in the new server I can attach it. Smaller VM works fine, but there's this one disk (about 2tb) that it's taking and incredible amount of time (after 15h it's only at 17%) and I don't know why it's transfering at only 10mb/s (everything is working on 10gb Eth). So, because I need to access the file in that VM, I want to safely stop the move operation.
From esxi it doesn't let me cancel the task (the cancel is greyed out). What can I do? Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
